# Popup Menu not expanding (popup height is always the same)

Tags: android, android-menu, android-popupwindow

```
MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

**Code from MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.action_sort:
        showSortPopup(item.getActionView());
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void showSortPopup(View view) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

**sort_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_ascending"
              android:title="Ascending" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_descending"
              android:title="Descending" />
</menu>
```

And this is the Popup Menu that is showed when *R.id.action_sort* action bar menu is selected: 
[image: Popup bug preview] 
 
It works, I mean I can scroll it to see other menu items but why it's not expanding ?

Comment: I think it may be a bug from `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light` theme.